# how to add visual c++ template to visual studio 2010 ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

i recently installed visual studio 2010 ultimate with visual c#. Now i want to program in visual c++, how can i install the visual c++ template?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start the Visual Studio installer again and change the selected set of features.

Answer (score 0):

Try to search in online templates section under New->Project and then in the left side of the window.

TO restore all templates,Close all instance of Visual Studio. Open visual studio command prompt and traverse to ../Microsoftvisualstudioxxxx/common7/IDE and then type

```
            **devenv /installvstemplates**
```

in command prompt. Wait for sometime until all templates are restored.